# Displaying an image in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display an image on a UICollectionViewCell:

Here is the Page Class:

```
struct Page {
        let imageName: UIImageView
        let headerText: String
        let bodyText: String
    }
```

Here is where I assign the image and text to each part of the view:

```
func one(){
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "burger"))

        pages = [
            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText"),

            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText"),

            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText"),

            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText"),

            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText"),

            Page(imageName: imageView, headerText: "headerText", bodyText: "bodyText")
        ]
    }
```

This is how I set image constraints:

```
  private let bearImageView: UIImageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "burger"))
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            return imageView
        }()
```

also

```
let topImageContainerView = UIView()
        addSubview(topImageContainerView)

        topImageContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        topImageContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true

        topImageContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        topImageContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    topImageContainerView.addSubview(bearImageView)
            bearImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topImageContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            bearImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topImageContainerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            bearImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topImageContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
```

The problem is that when I run the code the text is displayed perfectly, but the image is no appearing at all.

I am totally lost with this and any help would be welcome!

Comment: What's this?  let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "burger"))  That's not how you instantiate a UIImageView object.

Comment: @ElTomato that how it displays when copy and pasted. it displays like this for me :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz8KT.png

Answer (score 1):

You use a refrence type imageView inside a struct

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "burger"))
```

it will be 1 item eventuallyb regardless of `posts` count , despite you should have

```
let imageName: String
```

or

```
let image: UImage
```

> Outlets are weak so when you assign `UIImageView` type it won't be retained even for that 1 single imageView object

---

**Edit :** set a height constraint for `topImageContainerView` and a bottom to view same for the inner imageView

Comment: thank you for your response, i have changed image class to UIImage as suggested  and set the image as follows: let imageView: UIImage = UIImage(named: "burger")!  and still it does not work :(

Comment: how do you set constraints of imageview share code ?

Comment: did you have a chance to look at this?

Comment: should be now, apologies

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. What do you want me to post?